# SQLPLUS value in variable- not working from crontab

Tags: linux, cron, ksh, variable

I am trying to store sqlplus value to a variable in Linux.

Script is working fine when triggered manually. But value in variable is not stored when the script is called from crontab.

Code:

```
#!/bin/ksh
~/.profile
v=`sqlplus -s <<!
<<DB details>>
select sysdate from dual;
!
`
echo "$v"
```

Comment: Are you sure `~` has the same meaning from CRON and from your terminal? Are both running as the same user?

Comment: Script is picked by crontab and it invoked .profile too. but the value for the variable remains blank(unset)

Answer (score 3):

Running `sqlplus` from a crontab entry can be frustrating. You get a very sparse PATH variable as the shell that `crond` forks off does not read the "rc" file.

In your ".profile" file do you set ORACLE_HOME?  Do you include $ORACLE_HOME/bin in the PATH, and export ORACLE_HOME and PATH? Check that first. Also, I have to note that your code shows the `ksh` in question *executing* not *sourcing* the `~/.profile` file. Your script should "source" that file. I also seem to have a superstition about setting and exporting TNS_ADMIN, like this:

```
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
```

You can include database user ID and password in the "here document" by using the `/nolog` option of `sqlplus` to avoid flashing those details to anyone who runs `ps`:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog 2>&1 << END_ZERO_ROW_CHECK
connect $USER_NAME/$PASSWORD@$SID_INSTANCE
whenever oserror exit failure
whenever sqlerror exit failure
...
END_ZERO_ROW_CHECK
```

Comment: This is almost guaranteed to be your problem.  Bruce describes it well.  It is largely an environment (PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH ) issue combined with making sqlplus behave as you want.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, 
But my .profile indeed contains :    PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH:/sbin:/opt/oracle/product/102010_cl_64/cl/bin:/opt/oracle/product/102010_cl_64/cl/lib:/usr/local/sbin:/opt/oracle/product/102010_cl_64/cl/bin
export PATH
 and   ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/102010_cl_64/cl
export ORACLE_HOME
    but it is still not setting the variable value.

Comment: @user3377923 - your .profile may indeed contain that, but your script doesn't source .profile, it executes it. put ".  " (dot space) in front of "~/.profile" to get ksh to source .profile rather than execute it.